# How long an iOS app install via firebase beta can be used

Tags: ios, software-distribution, firebase-app-distribution

I'm distributing beta versions of an iOS app to our members. I'm wondering if there is time limit for the apps to be alive. An app installed via firebase beta can be used forever or it will somehow expire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [Firebase App Distribution troubleshooting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/troubleshooting?platform=ios#app_releases_expire_after_150_days_2) app releases expire after 150 days.